# Symbolicate Crash Log Apple IOS 14

Tags: ios, angular, crash, nativescript

A week ago I published my app made with nativescript angular to appstore connect and it was rejected because they say the app crash on launch. The crash doesn't happen with me in debug so I wanted to decrypt the crashlog they send me to figure out what causes the crash.
The problem is that I cannot symbolicate the crash log from Xcode 12, when I drag and drop the crash file to device log, nothing happen. Apple send me only the crash log without the Dsym file so I tried the commands to get the path to Dsym without success.

```
% grep --after-context=1000 "Binary Images:" path/to/crash | grep libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1d7dcd000 - 0x1d7dfefff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <03a89b86f9473933b6a1edb0c6a2055e>

% mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 03A89B86-F947-3933-B6A1-EDB0C6A2055E"
```

Here's one of the crashlog.txt I received from apple:

```
{"app_name":"TinaApp","timestamp":"2020-11-30 11:42:13.00 -0800","app_version":"1.1","slice_uuid":"aebc048e-2b6a-3fb6-ab18-3141389f0cb8","adam_id":1541530452,"build_version":"1.1","platform":2,"bundleID":"org.nativescript.TinaAppIos","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 14.2 (18B92)","incident_id":"A57AA910-383F-4D84-A606-EC27FA4224BB","name":"TinaApp"}
Incident Identifier: A57AA910-383F-4D84-A606-EC27FA4224BB
CrashReporter Key:   4146dc498fcd4cb0b21ecb5485ee3b2820a520b1
Hardware Model:      iPad11,3
Process:             TinaApp [533]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/42A6C1C0-755E-461C-AD6A-5E81B2616016/TinaApp.app/TinaApp
Identifier:          org.nativescript.TinaAppIos
Version:             1.1 (1.1)
AppStoreTools:       12B45a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.nativescript.TinaAppIos [584]


Date/Time:           2020-11-30 11:42:12.8597 -0800
Launch Time:         2020-11-30 11:42:12.6230 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.2 (18B92)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000002838ae8
VM Region Info: 0x2838ae8 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4288378136
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   1021f0000-1021f4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...p.app/TinaApp

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [533]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001bfad7658 0x1bfad2000 + 22104
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001bfad7f88 0x1bfad2000 + 24456
2   NativeScript                    0x0000000102c8d61c 0x102c14000 + 497180
3   NativeScript                    0x0000000102c71fc8 0x102c14000 + 384968
4   NativeScript                    0x0000000102c1d0b8 0x102c14000 + 37048
5   NativeScript                    0x00000001037a9b00 0x102c14000 + 12147456
6   NativeScript                    0x0000000102d55ce4 0x102c14000 + 1318116
7   NativeScript                    0x0000000103453184 0x102c14000 + 8647044
8   NativeScript                    0x00000001030665d4 0x102c14000 + 4531668
9   NativeScript                    0x00000001037b5124 0x102c14000 + 12194084
10  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
11  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
12  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
13  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
14  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
15  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
16  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
17  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
18  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
19  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
20  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
21  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
22  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
23  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
24  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
25  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
26  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
27  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
28  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
29  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
30  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
31  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
32  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
33  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
34  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
35  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c8220 0x102c14000 + 12272160
36  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
37  NativeScript                    0x00000001037a9988 0x102c14000 + 12147080
38  NativeScript                    0x0000000102d55c6c 0x102c14000 + 1317996
39  NativeScript                    0x00000001035fae98 0x102c14000 + 10383000
40  NativeScript                    0x0000000102c35550 0x102c14000 + 136528
41  NativeScript                    0x00000001034c87e0 0x102c14000 + 9127904
42  NativeScript                    0x00000001037cab6c 0x102c14000 + 12282732
43  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
44  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
45  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
46  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c8220 0x102c14000 + 12272160
47  NativeScript                    0x00000001037c82c8 0x102c14000 + 12272328
48  NativeScript                    0x00000001037a9988 0x102c14000 + 12147080
49  NativeScript                    0x0000000102d55c6c 0x102c14000 + 1317996
50  NativeScript                    0x00000001035fb050 0x102c14000 + 10383440
51  NativeScript                    0x00000001034c1b08 0x102c14000 + 9100040
52  NativeScript                    0x0000000102c2ae90 0x102c14000 + 93840
53  NativeScript                    0x0000000102ca12d8 0x102c14000 + 578264
54  TinaApp                         0x00000001021f4fb0 0x1021f0000 + 20400
55  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ab1b76c0 0x1ab1b6000 + 5824

Thread 1 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d7df51ac 0x1d7dcd000 + 164268
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cf6458 0x1f3cf1000 + 21592
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001bfb793c4 0x1bfb6c000 + 54212
3   NativeScript                    0x0000000102cd3cbc 0x102c14000 + 785596
4   NativeScript                    0x0000000102cd28b8 0x102c14000 + 780472
5   NativeScript                    0x0000000102cd2530 0x102c14000 + 779568
6   NativeScript                    0x0000000102cd387c 0x102c14000 + 784508
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cf2b40 0x1f3cf1000 + 6976
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cfb768 0x1f3cf1000 + 42856

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cfb754 0x1f3cf1000 + 42836

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cfb754 0x1f3cf1000 + 42836

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f3cfb754 0x1f3cf1000 + 42836

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000002838ae0   x1: 0x00000002838ae6e0   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000034
    x4: 0x0000000000000603   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x832b7e01ab58f7e0
    x8: 0x0000000002838ae8   x9: 0x0300c41631f8e549  x10: 0x0000c41439270000  x11: 0x0000000000000135
   x12: 0x0000000000000e2b  x13: 0x000000016db04000  x14: 0x00000000000eb9e0  x15: 0x000000016daf4000
   x16: 0x00000001bfad7f6c  x17: 0x00000001adb15e88  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000020
   x20: 0x0300000208dfe549  x21: 0x00000002838ae6e0  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000103983000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000016dc0ddf0  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000104e0e6c8
   x28: 0x0000000104e0e6b8   fp: 0x000000016dc0d870   lr: 0x00000001bfad7f88
    sp: 0x000000016dc0d870   pc: 0x00000001bfad7658 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:

0x1bc9aa000 - 0x1bcbfbfff NetworkExtension arm64e  <7ac80cf832e036d5bc42ebbec342d1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/NetworkExtension
0x1bcff3000 - 0x1bd777fff Espresso arm64e  <97fef9db244332f8b2ea5d8cc39f5fa8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Espresso.framework/Espresso
0x1bd778000 - 0x1bd875fff VideoToolbox arm64e  <ed510ff4c5eb3ce9ac213c26f1bccfd0> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x1bd9c0000 - 0x1bd9d1fff AXCoreUtilities arm64e  <cca3207470b434a68053f1b444f562fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AXCoreUtilities.framework/AXCoreUtilities
0x1bea3e000 - 0x1beb52fff LanguageModeling arm64e  <e46094d442ef33c8a0b7f3d2f51029b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x1beb53000 - 0x1beb5bfff InternationalSupport arm64e  <2c388cf5fcf33c7287ef2722b5dc425e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/InternationalSupport.framework/InternationalSupport
0x1bf29a000 - 0x1bf2abfff UniformTypeIdentifiers arm64e  <7f27c250b622344a9d5294869043304a> /System/Library/Frameworks/UniformTypeIdentifiers.framework/UniformTypeIdentifiers
0x1bfad2000 - 0x1bfb08fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <282fd01c1437349bae1a2eff32859670> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1bfb09000 - 0x1bfb6bfff LoggingSupport arm64e  <156505e355a636b2ac5aadc43aaa0448> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoggingSupport.framework/LoggingSupport
0x1bfb6c000 - 0x1bfbcafff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <540a1413a396391a83dbfe9ee2bc1413> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1bfbcb000 - 0x1bfbe4fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <44a88d84a05435cdbaed93bd792990ab> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1bfd68000 - 0x1bfdabfff CoreAutoLayout arm64e  <42d414ddf9b538aa98fb89fa71c952fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework/CoreAutoLayout
0x1bfdac000 - 0x1bff0afff Network arm64e  <8bd5299e8c953974be90e1bc68051c94> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Network
0x1bff0b000 - 0x1bff41fff MobileKeyBag arm64e  <3fdf1dfdb0603c2989e11f25def200fd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1c0198000 - 0x1c024afff libvDSP.dylib arm64e  <97919760f4313342a4339f60c012efeb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1c024b000 - 0x1c027efff libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib arm64e  <5d96fa7f071331e5be77e36816ec884c> /usr/lib/libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib
0x1c044b000 - 0x1c04d7fff CoreNLP arm64e  <082ab669b28430eca3b0c0d2075799e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreNLP.framework/CoreNLP
0x1c04d8000 - 0x1c05f2fff FileProvider arm64e  <837422b0fdb2379aba3dabae17cfd66d> /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/FileProvider
0x1c0654000 - 0x1c06e4fff Symbolication arm64e  <92c59ae0a084347489ec51e75d1e9722> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symbolication.framework/Symbolication
0x1c06e5000 - 0x1c0702fff CrashReporterSupport arm64e  <012daa6ec5523a3483eb9ab77e4b737a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x1c084d000 - 0x1c0a38fff MPSNeuralNetwork arm64e  <8f57a915cad530579febd66886f15bc9> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSNeuralNetwork.framework/MPSNeuralNetwork
0x1c0a39000 - 0x1c0a8efff MPSCore arm64e  <d9092029fb813e67a51d75b05e47f999> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Frameworks/MPSCore.framework/MPSCore
0x1c0e31000 - 0x1c0ee1fff libboringssl.dylib arm64e  <6323c8b4e8de3628815bdc09daa662e7> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x1c0ee2000 - 0x1c0ef9fff ProtocolBuffer arm64e  <7d8c52408219342f95be0602a19661de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1c117a000 - 0x1c1189fff AssertionServices arm64e  <9744262405dc374a90194c2520e5f3cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1c1206000 - 0x1c12e6fff Metal arm64e  <7eba2500a6bb3049adf3bb6649b0e3ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x1c12e7000 - 0x1c1432fff MediaExperience arm64e  <e35ad2f50c2c3d908c8f127aa40412c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaExperience.framework/MediaExperience
0x1c183f000 - 0x1c1855fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64e  <4cc641303c003e0d9f9329f250e62552> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1c1b29000 - 0x1c1bc5fff AppStoreDaemon arm64e  <8f3015067d2b35c09f00e913753e4b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppStoreDaemon.framework/AppStoreDaemon
0x1c2573000 - 0x1c257bfff GraphicsServices arm64e  <d365efcf659c3292b2035692107edd1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1c274c000 - 0x1c2761fff PowerLog arm64e  <5d44ee361a573a0f849cd6beffa79b02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1c439f000 - 0x1c43befff ApplePushService arm64e  <b0f41c66957230bb8b651acce9d3f111> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x1c43bf000 - 0x1c43e8fff BoardServices arm64e  <77316d31a9c330faa15c36e9480551bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BoardServices.framework/BoardServices
0x1c4586000 - 0x1c45d4fff OSAnalytics arm64e  <e3c7d8e9934e336ab5722435255eec40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OSAnalytics.framework/OSAnalytics
0x1c45d5000 - 0x1c465dfff CoreBluetooth arm64e  <0d965ffce4223038998e1f54ecf268ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1c488d000 - 0x1c48c2fff MobileInstallation arm64e  <6d1f04bb59123d149f2ede2d2d3d75c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x1c48c3000 - 0x1c4951fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64e  <5a9d29cff0523cd9b6dba5763611b94f> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1c4952000 - 0x1c49c1fff NanoRegistry arm64e  <91e1b16b28e03d2f918684c5e58d5b5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NanoRegistry.framework/NanoRegistry
0x1c4aa5000 - 0x1c4ac3fff CoreMaterial arm64e  <dd53656ef2683b8f9d75d63a83631dc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMaterial.framework/CoreMaterial
0x1c4b39000 - 0x1c4cc2fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64e  <8d5e6b031eb130a39baf1ca70bacc372> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1c4cc3000 - 0x1c4d87fff AVFCapture arm64e  <a57415fcfda0315e9fcae8a62537d242> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AVFCapture.framework/AVFCapture
0x1c4d88000 - 0x1c50d7fff CMCapture arm64e  <46eeaeff64ea3b7d965e76b5908f032b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CMCapture.framework/CMCapture
0x1c58c0000 - 0x1c58cafff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64e  <94a64f0e93bc34a49da750227bb11e7d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1c58cb000 - 0x1c5910fff CryptoTokenKit arm64e  <4a0f3265f569378cb3525f370f17a5ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/CryptoTokenKit
0x1c597e000 - 0x1c59eefff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64e  <8e5a940be1f2393f98fb3c11ca9d7af1> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1c59ef000 - 0x1c5a13fff UserManagement arm64e  <9de84926582f3f1396b93727ec7352c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x1c5af0000 - 0x1c5b06fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64e  <aaf99de1c3b73654adf0d1e1873d4f0f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1c5dc7000 - 0x1c5dfefff CoreServicesStore arm64e  <076898ab5fb830398e3b27506126ba4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/CoreServicesStore
0x1c5dff000 - 0x1c5e24fff CoreAnalytics arm64e  <0a6e0f29ed4c393385f411112b49355b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/CoreAnalytics
0x1c5e25000 - 0x1c5e30fff SymptomAnalytics arm64e  <232c8335dd803d9d96df286a12717e9b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Symptoms.framework/Frameworks/SymptomAnalytics.framework/SymptomAnalytics
0x1c6023000 - 0x1c6033fff NanoPreferencesSync arm64e  <c8aa03aea8363e12a9462dfde95e8ee0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NanoPreferencesSync.framework/NanoPreferencesSync
0x1c64f2000 - 0x1c651efff IconServices arm64e  <1fefb8bca4b1319a8f6cd4762169681d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IconServices.framework/IconServices
0x1c6fc4000 - 0x1c728bfff vImage arm64e  <5fb545f9e9d332cc81a355d4c9bb880d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x1c8225000 - 0x1c827efff ktrace arm64e  <ddfb6a09ddc734a9bde86db4e94b5c03> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ktrace.framework/ktrace
0x1c83e4000 - 0x1c83f2fff Celestial arm64e  <00aeba1f574637f0984b61ac24956e02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x1c84e9000 - 0x1c864cfff WebKitLegacy arm64e  <bef4cbf477313a539a11b88c67294e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x1c8738000 - 0x1c877ffff StoreKit arm64e  <e8001f10f70134a4b4e2a976e329fecd> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x1c9610000 - 0x1c961afff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64e  <63c1e7be31663cfda08b7d8128d4e97c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x1c9cad000 - 0x1c9ccdfff PrototypeTools arm64e  <4e97be2ee39b3a7584ae3d6d728e0caa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrototypeTools.framework/PrototypeTools
0x1c9cce000 - 0x1c9cfbfff PersistentConnection arm64e  <dc9ebb9f1d5431db8852fc138cc1bf15> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x1ca6cf000 - 0x1ca6e5fff AppSSOCore arm64e  <1c1432c99af13d519da74f63e0746c96> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSSOCore.framework/AppSSOCore
0x1ca709000 - 0x1ca782fff Rapport arm64e  <44ded582498c3a57a4f7abdb23ea224b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Rapport.framework/Rapport
0x1cab4b000 - 0x1cab72fff LocationSupport arm64e  <9d8855fe37393a24bbab3d4e76bc9acd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LocationSupport.framework/LocationSupport
0x1caee9000 - 0x1caeebfff OSAServicesClient arm64e  <84221a68b21e3502b82f84c94ad26ee7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OSAServicesClient.framework/OSAServicesClient
0x1caeef000 - 0x1caf49fff ProtectedCloudStorage arm64e  <29cc7c700ce03a59b6a1d3455cab774d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtectedCloudStorage.framework/ProtectedCloudStorage
0x1caf4a000 - 0x1caf82fff C2 arm64e  <5a0774b8b1e132af8c1026ec50dde08e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/C2.framework/C2
0x1cba1f000 - 0x1cba63fff BiometricKit arm64e  <9734ad9cd03d30499fce53c0b1aaf7de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BiometricKit.framework/BiometricKit
0x1cbaab000 - 0x1cbb60fff CoreSymbolication arm64e  <954762d29e123e34b471bd6dcb9a574f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/CoreSymbolication
0x1cc2f3000 - 0x1cc305fff IOSurface arm64e  <5dffebfea4823ad79be8e6a90b48af4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x1cc306000 - 0x1cc367fff MobileWiFi arm64e  <18d519d1ec90350b8dc1bfcba45b5bc7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x1cc8f5000 - 0x1cc930fff libGLImage.dylib arm64e  <9c29d9d8bdf93cfcbefe7cdc973e6347> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x1cc931000 - 0x1cc938fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64e  <3bfbc8597697318ba51c93ce93998184> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1cc97e000 - 0x1ccedefff CoreAudio arm64e  <5b9f4eac9bda3cdab15737003aa2941b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1cd573000 - 0x1cd583fff CoreAUC arm64e  <40b962c8f93938a5896616ace7160756> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x1cdda5000 - 0x1cddb6fff SettingsFoundation arm64e  <800ca3683d4435fda6b1c27a00a4b9aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SettingsFoundation.framework/SettingsFoundation
0x1cf06f000 - 0x1cf07cfff MediaSafetyNet arm64e  <34ef1af0b3a23b61ac9e8d081bbbe7c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaSafetyNet.framework/MediaSafetyNet
0x1cf07d000 - 0x1cf0bafff TimeSync arm64e  <f699ac049e4c33e6ae7b5343cf75c8bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TimeSync.framework/TimeSync
0x1cf114000 - 0x1cf158fff ExposureNotification arm64e  <882988aa081b374298a4f650547525e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExposureNotification.framework/ExposureNotification
0x1cf7e0000 - 0x1cf7e9fff CoreTime arm64e  <6ca04258877e323083716a08a4355207> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x1d03d2000 - 0x1d03dbfff ContextKitExtraction arm64e  <8e76a030982437b9b060134a2404cbd5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContextKitExtraction.framework/ContextKitExtraction
0x1d1d16000 - 0x1d1d25fff MobileIcons arm64e  <2824819666923b6cb04cd857938118fd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x1d3414000 - 0x1d341efff MallocStackLogging arm64e  <1999968e5c0c3d23b4bb13a646bf02ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MallocStackLogging.framework/MallocStackLogging
0x1d365b000 - 0x1d36a6fff MetadataUtilities arm64e  <cfe79278ad7838789c6ff37f8f2fcfe0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/MetadataUtilities
0x1d3dd3000 - 0x1d3e32fff CoreLocationProtobuf arm64e  <4766381daa153619836a933d9eb61faf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreLocationProtobuf.framework/CoreLocationProtobuf
0x1d4047000 - 0x1d4079fff Bom arm64e  <e179e70a012230199d058d948c56de9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x1d40ac000 - 0x1d40b3fff PushKit arm64e  <fbffaa0fad463f78b1b99c48bc4aa066> /System/Library/Frameworks/PushKit.framework/PushKit
0x1d42bc000 - 0x1d434cfff Quagga arm64e  <c2bad99ea9af3d88ad4127c9129cf77d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x1d434d000 - 0x1d4355fff StudyLog arm64e  <661715f078e037ce8df4a601b017c25a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StudyLog.framework/StudyLog
0x1d7489000 - 0x1d7494fff AppleIDAuthSupport arm64e  <f1a434dbd2a532049eb7775f4fa8f8e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleIDAuthSupport.framework/AppleIDAuthSupport
0x1d74a4000 - 0x1d74bdfff LocalAuthentication arm64e  <163267374c1f3c509f15aeb1df0f9e40> /System/Library/Frameworks/LocalAuthentication.framework/LocalAuthentication
0x1d7538000 - 0x1d753efff IOAccelerator arm64e  <a08924030b463468ad339a36407ce19e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x1d7dcd000 - 0x1d7dfefff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <03a89b86f9473933b6a1edb0c6a2055e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib

EOF
```

I didn't post all the file because I'm limited to 30000 characters.

My package.json:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": {
      "android": "org.nativescript.TinaApp",
      "ios": "org.nativescript.TinaAppIos"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.3.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.3",
    "nativescript-datetimepicker": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.5.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
    "platform": "^1.3.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.3.2",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^6.5.15",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.5.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.19.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "fa98f785df3fba482e5e2a0c76f4be1fa6dc7a14",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

My nativescript version is 6.3.3 and I use Xcode 12.

Comment: did you find a solution?